# Should I store HTML as nvarchar(MAX) or ntext?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I don't know if there's a limit to the number of characters if I choose nvarchar(MAX), and I'm not sure how many characters I would need anyways.

What's the standard data type to use here? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `ntext` type is deprecated, as are `text` and `image`. Microsoft recommends replacing them with `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)` respectively.

Use `nvarchar(max)`, therefore.

Reference:

- [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

The advantages of using nvarchar(MAX) are that you can run functions such as Replace, Left, Len etc on nvarchar(MAX) but not on ntext. ntext local variables also cannot be created in stored procedures however nvarchar(MAX) can.

ntext is also likely to be deprecated in the future in favour of nvarchar(MAX) see:

[ntext, text, and image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The default setting for NVARCHAR(MAX) is to store its text value in the table structure, unless the text is over 8,000 bytes (which is 4000 double-byte chars), at which point it behaves like an NTEXT and stores the text value in the LOB, and stores a pointer to the text in the table - which gives much worse performance.

In short, go for `NVARCHAR(4000)`, as long as it's OK to lose bytes over 8K long.

Comment: The maximum explicit limit for `nvarchar` is 4000. 8000 is for `varchar`.

Comment: thx. edited answer to reflect this (ie is 8K = 4K double-byte chars)

Comment: When would it ever be "OK" to lose data?

Comment: @Aaron What if the URL was a multi-gigebyte uncompressed bluray movie? Would it be OK to store it in the DB?

Comment: If that's the requirement, sure. The OP indicated they are storing HTML and choosing between nvarchar and ntext, so I'm guessing that's because the HTML can potentially exceed 4K characters, not because they were interested in storing truncated versions of their HTML.