# Are there any concerns moving from ntext to nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Is there any concern about change my column type from text/ntext to varchar(max)/nvarchar(max)?

Could it break anything? Example, sprocs that has ntext parameters...

Comment: You mean other than ntext being deprecated?  Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975947/should-i-store-html-as-nvarcharmax-or-ntext

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think the OP is already correctly moving from `NTEXT` to `NVARCHAR`, but is wondering if there is any danger for anything to break as a result.

Comment: Ah, yes, read it backwards.  *Question titles are so important.*

Comment: The biggest challenge might be convincing others who have "always done it this way" and see no reason to change. After 2+ years of trying at work, I finally gave up. Sacred cows die hard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few concerns, for example if you are currently using the following functions:

- [`UPDATETEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189466.aspx)
- [`WRITETEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186838.aspx)
- [`READTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187365.aspx)
- [`TEXTPTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176068.aspx)

You might want to perform a search of your codebase to identify these - grep your applications and/or source control if you use ad hoc SQL, or search stored procedures etc. using the following:

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]), OBJECT_NAME([object_id])
  FROM sys.sql_modules
  WHERE [definition] LIKE '%WRITETEXT%'
     OR [definition] LIKE '%READTEXT%'
     OR [definition] LIKE '%UPDATETEXT%'
     OR [definition] LIKE '%TEXTPTR%';
```

You can also identify procedures and functions with these parameters (I included both `TEXT` and `NTEXT`) using:

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]), OBJECT_NAME([object_id]), name
  FROM sys.parameters
  WHERE system_type_id IN (35, 99);
```

And tables/views/TVFs with these column types using:

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]), OBJECT_NAME([object_id]), name
  FROM sys.columns
  WHERE system_type_id IN (35, 99);
```

Or - and I am not sure about all APIs / providers - but some might have an issue swapping out `ntext` parameters for `nvarchar` (and you might have to explicitly change some of your code to specify the max length of -1). It's been a long time since I worked on interface code when these types were still in fashion (~1999) so I apologize if my memory is hazy there.

You shouldn't have any breaking changes if your stored procedures continue to take `NTEXT` parameters, but you won't want to leave those that way for long.

Mostly you should just experience better performance, easier data manipulation, and overall improved compatibility with the new type. Never mind future-proofing!

Comment: About the Views, I need to change or I should?

Comment: @Fujiy, if you are changing your columns to use the modern types, you should update any views that reference those tables using [`sp_refreshsqlmodule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326754.aspx). If you are talking about output columns in your views where you explicitly say `CONVERT(NTEXT, whatever)`, what possible benefit do you see from leaving them that way? If you're going to change the data types, change the data types. Don't do it half-way.

Comment: I intend to change everything, but the first step is convert the datatype and all applications should continue working. I will be careful to run sp_refreshsqlmodule for all views